# Probability 33 people in a group of 100,000 have the same birthday? Assuming years have 365,000 days.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, birthday

Probability 33 people in a group of 100,000 have the same birthday? Assuming years have 365,000 days.  Would this Poisson [Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYsFO.png) work?

Updated!

---

Note to OP:  Probability of *exactly* $33$ people have the same birthday?  Or probability of *at least* $33$ people have the same birthday?  Or probability that *exactly* $33$ people have the same birthday and possibly another group of $33$ has the same (but different) birthday?  Or probability that *a given preselected group of 33 people* have the same birthday?  Or.....

Comment: Probability of some set has *exactly* $33$?  Or has *at least* $33$?  Or some particular set of $33$ has the same birthday?

Comment: How many days are assumed in a year, $365$?

Comment: @NazimJ:  Do you think your answer would differ significantly if you used $364$ versus $365$?  Doesn't *every* problem of this sort assume $365$?

Comment: I don't know what every problem assumes, that's why I ask. It could be the case that pigeonhole principle implies there is always 33 people with the same bday (who knows).  And it could be the case pigeonhole principle only gives you enought buckets assuming 364 instead of 365 (i dont know, havent started working the problem out yet).  So for me it matters, yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of part of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173697/probability-of-n-people-in-a-group-of-m-where-mn-having-the-same-birthday

Comment: @NazimJ:  You're mathematical intuitions need a *lot* of refining if you think that there will be a *qualitative* difference between $365$ and $364$, as you apparently do.

Comment: If I want to try the pigeonhole principle, the number of buckets that can be created matters.  Before working it out myself, I ask OP to confirm for me how many days there are to choose from.  No big deal.

Comment: The number of days does bring up an interesting thought though. What if hypothetically our sun's gravitational pull was slowed by a black hole and our years now had 365,000 days?

Comment: But very very poorly (e.g., saying "years have 365k days *twice*!!).  Its has the irrelevant keyword "black hole" (which will confuse searchers) and you refuse to specify the *precise* problem as numerous people here have complained.  "the birthday paradox"?   Huh?  More waste of time.

Comment: Nobody can answer a poorly specified question... and you're wasting our time because you don't realize how poorly specified your question is.  Over and out.

Comment: Clear expert advice was given in your problem.  Not much more we can do for you.

Comment: lol. No one has answered the question. I think you have to go back to first grade and learn how to read.